# fetch API, re-Post formData on useFinalURL

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Is there a way to re-Post my formData after fetch.Response is a redirect anymore?

My first request (to which I send my Post data) gets a 301 Code, this is ok - but how can I resend my Post-Request if the next (or next next) Response is the useFinalURL?

Example:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'post',
  body: formData,
  redirect: 'follow'
})
.then(function(response) {
  if (response.useFinalURL === true){ resendFetchPost }
})
```

Hope someone can give me an hint

Comment: Make it a recursive function `const fetchSomething = (formData, url) => fetch(url, {...}).then(resp => resp.finalURL === true ? fetchSomething(formData, url) : resp.text());`

Comment: I'm pretty sure `fetch` already does this for you, especially since you've set `redirect: 'follow'`.

Comment: @Walk that may be correct, it's a fairly new API and I'm not totally familiar with it. Also, now that I think about it I believe the correct property name is `useFinalURL` not `finalUrl`.

Comment: @Walk I'm sorry I think it doesn't, its ok - fetch follows the redirect, but it does not resend the POST Data. Because it is a 301 Redirect, not a 307 - unfortunately

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks, that is correct. It should be ```useFinalURL```

Comment: I was wrong. "If either actualResponse’s status is 301 or 302 and request’s method is `POST`, or actualResponse’s status is 303, set request’s method to `GET` and request’s body to null." Using recursion as @JaredSmith wrote should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to redo something based on a conditional check the easiest solution is usually a recursive function:

```
const autoPost = (url, formData) => {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    redirect: 'follow'
  }).then(resp => {
    return resp.useFinalURL ? 
      autoPost(resp.url, formData) : // resend to final url
      resp.text(); // could sub resp.json() as approp.
  });
};
```

Added bonus, since `fetch` is asynchronous you won't get an infinite recursion error thrown or block endlessly.